# Find the number of ways to select three distinct digits from the set{0,1,2, . . . ,9} if no two consecutive digits can be selected

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

My professor answered this question to be $\binom{8}{3}$,but I'm still confused as how he got that number. Also I am confused by the meaning of "no two consecutive digits".

Can anyone help me understand what this problem is asking?

Thank you!

Comment: This is equivalent of proving that how many ways  u can make sequences of p 1's and q 0 's such that no two 1's are adjacent. This is easy now you can create a bijection between this problem and the above problem you have given.

Comment: I don't understand the question , you are asking to choose 3 distinct digits, yet you are saying that no two consecutive digits can be selected? That is obvious that we cannot choose the same digit consecutive or not!

Comment: @Riju This is what my textbook is asking. I'm sorry if you don't understand the question because quiet frankly I don't either.

Comment: No two consecutive digits means that while the selection $\{2, 5, 7\}$ is acceptable, the selection $\{2, 6, 7\}$ is not since $6$ and $7$ are consecutive.

Comment: @ChirantanChowdhury That concept is confusing me even more, but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig oh that makes sense. Thanks. Know if only I can understand how to solve this problem lol.

Comment: Did your professor provide an explanation for the answer?  For instance, did he use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle or place objects in gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to solve this problem.  I will restrict my attention to methods that lead directly to the answer $\binom{8}{3}$.

**Method 1:**  Line up eight balls, each of a different color, none of which is red.  Choose three of the eight balls.  Next, insert a red ball to the immediate right of the two leftmost balls you selected.  Now, number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the three balls you originally selected are the desired set of three non-consecutive integers.

Note that what we are doing here is setting up a bijection between three-element subsets $\{a, b, c\}$ of $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ with $a < b < c$ and three-element subsets $\{a, b + 1, c + 2\}$ of $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ in which no two of the elements are consecutive.

**Method 2:**  Line up seven blue balls, leaving spaces between them and at the ends of the row.  There are eight such spaces, six between successive balls and two at the ends of the row.  Now we place three green balls in the row.  To ensure that no two green balls are consecutive, we choose three of these eight spaces in which to place a green ball.  Now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the desired set of three non-consecutive integers.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I can see exactly what to do using either methods along with the "note". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

Write an arbitrary selection of $3$ out of $8$ as a binary word, like so: $01001100$. Now insert a $0$ after each of the first two $1$s (results in $0100010100$), and you obtain an admissible selection of $3$ out of $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok ,so let me explain here . First we solve the following problem:

Problem 1 :How many ways there are p $1$'s and q $0$'s such that  no two $1$'s are consecutive.
 I hope you can try this one and this shall be done . The answer is $\binom{q+1}{p}$.
Then we see the following question given by you in a general manner

Main problem :Now suppose you are given a set  $ \{ 1,2,3,..,p +q\} $. How many $p$ element subsets are there of this such that  no two elements are consecutive?

My claim is that it is same as the above one. This is because each sequence above gives such a subset of $S$ .
 A sequence $s$  of Problem 1 is a set of 1 and 0's of $p+q$ elements. The $1$'s occur at places $a_1,a_2,..a_p$ which are not consecutive. Map this sequence to the set :$ \{ a_1,a_2,..a_p \}  \subset S$ . Now you can see that this mapping between these two collections is a bijection. I hope this helps